# How do you sum numbers in a list of structs? (Racket)

Tags: list, struct, functional-programming, scheme, racket

I'm trying to sum all integers in a list of structs using a recursive function but cannot for the life of me figure it out.

```
(struct number (int))
(define ints (list (number 1)
                   (number 2)
                   (number 3)))

(define sum (λ (number)
            (cond
              ((null? number) 0) ; Base Case
              (#t (+ (number-int (car ints)) ; Take the first of the list
                     (sum (cdr ints))))))) ; Rest the list
```

I've spent **hours** trying different variations of:

> (cdr ints), i.e. (number-int (cdr ints)) for the last line

As I believe it's this which is causing the issue (both `(cdr ints)` and `(number-int (cdr ints))` return something in the form of `'(#<number> #<number>)`. But nothing seems to work!

Is there a procedure to returning the *cdr* of the list in the form of a list of integers rather than `'(#<number> #<number>)`?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "ints" is very badly named; suggests it's a list of ints but it's a list of "numbers" (i.e. structs); so better name could be `numbers`. 

then, define either `sum-numbers` function, to be called as `(sum-numbers numbers)`, or `sum-ints`, to be called as `(sum-ints (map number-int numbers))`. 

the first expects `numbers`, i.e. a list of `number` structs; the second expects a list of ints, so we must transform the list of "number" structs into a list of int numbers, for it (using `map`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
(define sum 
  (λ (lst)
    (cond ((null? lst) 0)
          (else (+ (number-int (car lst))
                   (sum (cdr lst)))))))
```

Some remarks:

- Use `else` instead of `#t` for the last condition in a `cond` expression
- You were mixing the name of the procedure's parameter `number` with the name of the `ints` list you defined outside
- Better rename it to `lst` or something else that makes it clear that is a *list* you're dealing with

Now it works as expected:

```
(sum ints)
=> 6
```

Answer (score 0):

A recursive named let with a variable to store sum values can be used:

```
(define (sum lst)
  (let loop ((lst lst)
             (s 0))
    (if (empty? lst)
        s
        (loop (cdr lst)
              (+ s
                 (number-int (car lst)))))))
```